# How do you use an update between two tables in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, updating

Hopefully this is relatively simple.  I want to update a table in Oracle but the data being compared is between two tables.  How can I accomplish this?  I tried the following SQL but know is incorrect after trying it:

```
           UPDATE gm_prc
           SET gm.RETAIL_DT = '01-JAN-2000'
           from gm_prc gm, itm_prc_cmp3 itm
           where gm.sku_num = itm.SKU_NUM
           and gm.PC_NUM = itm.PC_NUM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using doesn't work for Oracle.  But you can do this using standard SQL:

```
UPDATE gm_prc
    SET RETAIL_DT = '01-JAN-2000'
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM itm_prc_cmp3 itm
                  WHERE gm_prc.sku_num = itm.SKU_NUM AND
                        gm_prc.PC_NUM = itm.PC_NUM
                 );
```

This should work in both Oracle and SQL Server (which is what your syntax suggests for the original query).